# Python matching on repeated attributes

Tags: python

I have a list of objects, each with 3 attributes, and I want to find if any of my objects have any overlapping attributes, and pull them out as sets of objects with overlapping attributes.

Let me clarify:

```
class Obj():
    '''My example objects! they have 3 attributes.'''
    def __init__(a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

>>>> obj1 = Obj(a= 1, b = 2, c = 3)
>>>> obj2 = Obj(a= 1, b = 5, c = 6)
>>>> obj3 = Obj(a= 10, b = 12, c = 3)
>>>> obj4 = Obj(a= 0, b = 0, c = 0)
>>>> obj5 = Obj(a= 100, b = 5, c = 5)
>>>> obj6 = Obj(a = -10, b = 0, c = 56)
>>>> obj7 = Obj(a = None, b = None, c = None)

# obj2 matches obj1 on attribute: "a"
# obj3 matches obj1 on attribute: "c"
# obj5 matches obj2 on attribute: "b"

# obj6 matches obj4 on attribute: "b"

# obj7 matches no one
```

Therefore my output should be:

```
[[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj5], [obj4, obj6], [obj7]]
```

Is there a way I can do this with python? Also any key words I can search for things like this would be helpful.  I have attempted a solution below.  It seems...hacky.

Edit: 
had to change a few numbers to match my example.  sorry for the typo!

Edit: My current attempts at solutions:

```
adict = defaultdict(list)
for obj in list_objects:
    adict[obj.a].append(obj)
    adict[obj.b].append(obj)
    adict[obj.c].append(obj)
```

Then search for adict.values() for lists longer than 2.  Then combine lists (somehow).
I am hoping for an elegant solution?

Comment: So you want "matches" to be transitive—if obj2 matches obj1, and obj3 matches obj2, then obj3 matches obj1 even if they don't share any attributes?

Comment: Sounds like [Union Find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_find)

Comment: How do you want to handle the fact that `obj4` and `obj5` match on value `a`?

Comment: Also, as a side note: if you want sets, use `set`s, not `list`s. Your output should be `[{obj1, obj2, obj3, obj5}, {obj4, obj6}, {obj7}]`. That's more explicit and almost certainly more efficient, and it may even make your code easier to write.

Comment: @abarnert yes.  I am having trouble capturing the transitive-ness.  If obj2 matches obj1, and obj3 matches obj1, then they all match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole problem is described in terms of sets, so let's think of it in terms of sets. Put it in English-esque pseudocode first:

```
Start with an empty set of equivalence sets
For each value:
    Find all the equivalence sets that have any value that matches our value
    Remove those equivalent sets from the result set
    Union those equivalence sets together and add our new value
    Add that to the result set
```

That should do it, right?

In Python, an empty set is `set()`, you remove a value from a set by calling `s.remove(v)`, you add a value to a set by calling `s.add(v)`, and you union sets by calling (destructively) `s1 |= s2`, or (non-destructively) `s = set.union(s1, s2, s3, …)`. (You can use this together with `*` syntax: if you have a set of sets, or a list of sets, `set.union(*s)` gives you the union of them all.)

So, the only tricky bit is "find all equivalence sets that have any element that matches our element". The "… have any value that matches our value" is a call to `any` with a comprehension: `any(matches(value, element) for element in equivalenceset)`. And the "find all equivalence sets that…" is a comprehension: `{equivalenceset for equivalenceset in equivalencesets if …}`.

Obviously you also need to write that `matches` function, but that's easy: `x.a == y.a or x.b == y.b or x.c == y.c`.

That should be enough to write it all yourself.

Comment: sorry what am looping over in the for loop?  the input list of all objects? (that doesnt seem right?)

Comment: @user1639926: The outer loop is looping over the input list of all objects. Each one will get put into an equivalence set (possibly merging multiple equivalence sets together as it does so), one by one; once you've finished them all, everything is done. The inner loops in the comprehensions are looping over a single result equivalence set, and the full result set of equivalence sets, respectively.

Comment: @user1639926: If you're obliquely pointing out that this is going to be worst-case O(N^2)… then yes, that's true, but since you really do have to compare each object to each other object to find out if it matches (except in the case where you've already figured out that they match transitively, which this algorithm takes care of), I don't see any way around that.

Comment: Havent thought about the O() time yet.  Just trying to understand it.  My N is pretty small, 10-20 ish.

Comment: @user1639926: No problem. If there's any part you get stuck on (or that I got wrong… after all, pseudocode obviously isn't debugged), add another comment here, or if it deserves another question, create a new question.